# Two-step branch reintegration with TFS

Tags: tfs, merge, branch

On our TFS server, we have a trunk that is used for day-to-day development.  Nine months ago, I made a feature branch for what has become a fairly large refactoring of the code.  While I have been working on my branch, the other developer has been working directly on the trunk and building releases from there.  (Yes, I know this is bad practice.)  This means I can't merge my branch back into the trunk until it's been heavily tested, as new "production" builds are made from the trunk almost daily.  (Again, yes, I know this is bad practice.)

In order for other employees to test my branch before reintegration, I need a version with the last nine months of incremental updates from the trunk.  What I would like to do is merge the last nine months of changes from the trunk into my branch and then, after testing, merge my branch into the trunk.  Is this a common scenario?  Is it possible with TFS?  If so, what terminology should I use to search for tutorials, etc?  Or, if it can be described succinctly here, what are the steps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Merging changes back from a Main branch to a Dev branch is a common practice. I'm afraid however, that waiting nine months before you do it is not a common practice. Merging the changes after nine months is going to be hell.

The documentation you are looking for can be found here: [Merge folders and files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181428.aspx). The ALM Rangers have also published a guide on how to structure your branches and which options you have: [Version Control Guide](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Agreed on the pain. You're looking to `forward integrate` the changes into your feature branch, before you will `reverse integrate` them to the trunk. If development continues on the trunk while you work on this, expect a few long nights ahead to get some peace and quiet time.

Comment: Regarding the pain, there will definitely be some conflicts to resolve, but it's not as bad as it sounds.  For the most part the other developer and I have been working on separate, largely unrelated parts of the application.

Comment: @WouterdeKort, thanks again for this answer.  I did some testing with a small sample project and things worked as you said, but I wanted to be sure it worked with the real project before marking this as the accepted answer.  Today I did the final merge of my dev branch back into Main, and everything went very smoothly.